# How to count number of observations that were negative before receiving a positive result

Tags: r, group-by, count

I am working with some clinical data and I would like to count the number of tests someone had that were "Not Detected" before they had a "Detected" result and exclude anyone that never had a  "Detected" result.

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4)
Specimen_Type <- c("NP", "NP", "Throat", "Throat", "NP", "Throat", "Throat", "NP")
RESULT_VAL <- c("Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected")
RESULT_DATE <- c("6-1-2020", "6-10-2020","6-1-2020", "6-10-2020","6-1-2020", "6-10-2020", "6-20-2020", "6-1-2020")
Data_sum<- data.frame(ID, Specimen_Type, RESULT_VAL, RESULT_DATE)
```

I would like the output to look like this (or something like this) because I would also like to see how many different specimen types were used for testing prior to the positive result.

```
ID     Number_of_tests_before_pos     Specimen_Type     
1            1                              NP
2            1                              Throat 
3            2                              NP,Throat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', use `match` to get the index of the first occurrence of 'Detected' in 'RESULT_VAL' ('i1'), if there is no match, by default, returns `NA`, use that info to remove the IDs in `filter`, then we use `summarise` to get the count of 'Not Detected' in the subset of 'RESULT_VAL' until that index, similarly `paste` the `unique` elements of 'Specimen_Type' on the subset data

```
library(dplyr)
Data_sum %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(i1 = match('Detected', RESULT_VAL)) %>% 
   filter(complete.cases(i1)) %>%
   summarise(Number_of_tests_before_pos = sum(RESULT_VAL[seq(i1[1])] == 
          'Not Detected'),
          Specimen_Type = toString(unique(Specimen_Type[seq(i1[1])])),
           .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     ID Number_of_tests_before_pos Specimen_Type
#  <dbl>                      <int> <chr>        
#1     1                          1 NP           
#2     2                          1 Throat       
#3     3                          2 NP, Throat
```

---

Or we can can use `cumsum` on a logical vector to do the `filter`ing

```
Data_sum %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     filter(cumsum(RESULT_VAL == 'Detected') < 1,
            any(RESULT_VAL == 'Detected')) %>%
     summarise(Number_of_tests_before_pos = sum(RESULT_VAL == 'Not Detected'),
               Specimen_Type = toString(unique(Specimen_Type)), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     ID Number_of_tests_before_pos Specimen_Type
#  <dbl>                      <int> <chr>        
#1     1                          1 NP           
#2     2                          1 Throat       
#3     3                          2 NP, Throat
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option

```
transform(
  aggregate(
    . ~ ID,
    cbind(
      subset(Data_sum,
        ave(RESULT_VAL == "Detected", ID, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x) == 0 & any(x)),
        select = c(ID, Specimen_Type)
      ),
      Number_of_tests_before_pos = 1
    ),
    c
  ),
  Number_of_tests_before_pos = lengths(Number_of_tests_before_pos)
)
```

giving

```
  ID Specimen_Type Number_of_tests_before_pos
1  1            NP                          1
2  2        Throat                          1
3  3    NP, Throat                          2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first remove any `ID` that does not have `'Detected'` in `RESULT_VAL`, count number of rows before `'Detected'` and combine `Specimen_Type` into one-comma separated string.

```
library(dplyr)

Data_sum %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(RESULT_VAL == 'Detected')) %>%
  summarise(n = match('Detected', RESULT_VAL) - 1, 
            Specimen_Type = toString(Specimen_Type[1:n]))

#    ID     n Specimen_Type
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
#1     1     1 NP           
#2     2     1 Throat       
#3     3     2 NP, Throat
```